# How to UPDATE table data conditionally?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update table A with two data values from table B(back-up everyday On the day of the date) everyday, B has Millions of the number of levels data
The structure of table A and B is

```
A  -----Da   primary key  
   -----Db
B  -----Da  (table may have many Da data)
   -----Db
   -----....
```

Now,My SQL is :

```
INSERT INTO A (Da,Db)
    SELECT DISTINCT on(Da)Da,Db
    FROM B
    ON conflict(Da) DO UPDATE SET Db = excluded.Db
```

But It is inefficient,I think if make a judgment( Do nothing if A.Db=B.Db ) before UPDATE  will improve efficiency, Because A.Db=B.Db in most cases(About ninety-eight percent).
how to  write the code is a problem for me(I am not too familiar with SQL)..
Begged you a great god, and nasty! !

Answer (score 0):

An index on `B(Da, Db)` should probably fix any performance issues.

However, your query is not correct.  When using `DISTINCT ON`, you need `ORDER BY`:

```
INSERT INTO A (Da,Db)
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (Da) Da, Db
    FROM B
    ORDER BY Da, Db
    ON CONFLICT (Da) DO UPDATE SET Db = excluded.Db;
```

Comment: Right, but which of the `Db` for a certain `Da` do you want to have in the output?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I know what your mean,and the Db is the fixed if the Da is the same everyday,So I do not need to worry about the problem...(I have some trouble in English,Forgive me...)

Comment: @M.Mike . . . You have to worry about a `distinct on` query that does not use `order by`.  Period.  The query is not guaranteed to return the results in a particular order, unless you use `order by`.